# Css going away when hover

Tags: html, css

I got this problem that when I hover on video element then I lose the css (the border-radius is changing). Tts on the video row. Does any of you have any idea what I can do to fix it?
You can see my current site [here](http://hcl.konggulerodhosting.dk/index.html)

```
.gallery-image {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="large-3 columns">
    <div class="building-block-item">
        <div>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o7rdAH8oifo?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0. " class="gallery-video" data-featherlight="" data-featherlight-type="iframe">
                <div class="gallery-image">
                    <div class="gallery-veil">
                        <h3>Høreprøve</h3>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/images/video/video.png?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=282&amp;height=190&amp;rnd=130965782700000000&amp;quality=90">
                 </div>
             </a>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide example that illustrates issue. Link to your side is bad way to advertise.

Comment: Its the only example i got right now. You can try go in there and look.

Comment: Try to remove overflow:hidden from .gallery-image class.

Comment: @Leothelion Removing overflow hidden worked. But how?

Comment: there is this styling which i found while inspecting the element so I am not sure if this could solve the issue a img {
    /* border: 0; */
}

Comment: @StefanLarsen sorry my bad, overflow is solving issue but div is getting out so please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Nate please check my updated answer.

Comment: Previously, 2 things were animating on hover: the white to blue circle, and the opacity of the img overlay. With the accepted solution, the img opacity is no longer animating, and I think it's not as nice. Just before you implemented the change, I found that `transform: scale(1.02);` transforms for `.gallery-image img` fixed the issue, while keeping the img opacity animation. Let me know if you need me to explain.

Comment: @nate, transfrom:scale(1.02); will increase the image from inside and you will see the effect is same as with removing transition. If m not getting your  point then please let me know.. Will love to know :)

Comment: @Leothelion Using Chrome, I saw that removing those two transforms (transform and webkit-transform) fixed the curved-border issue. I saw no need for the minuscule scale to 102%, and guessed that this was ruining the css animation. You're saying that it provided a useful effect?

Comment: well i don't think that will be useful as it will change the way op wants. And op is quite happy with that so we should finish this. Have a nice day Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** Its because of `transition` so please remove transition from `.gallery-image img`

I have checked the code and found by removing overflow your div will go out of border(few px) so removing transition is better way. Your class will be look like this :

```
.gallery-image img
{
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why my menu is jumping around when i go on another page then?

Comment: you are talking about menu 1 menu 2 which is jumping for 2 sec?

Comment: Yep. I don't know why.. And when you hover over the a tag the white color it should have is getting some opacity i think. But i can't find anything and i does not remember that i gave it anything..

Comment: Please press f12 and go in console. You will see a lot js error..try to fix them and may be your issue will be solved so first solve them. Either js is conflating and also they are not available too.

Comment: If you are talking about green button which become little bit white on hover then yes coz you have used opacity in .button:focus, .button:hover {    background-color: rgba(155,173,80, .8);} so change the .8 to 1 and you are done.

Comment: I'm not talking about the green button.. I'm talking about that the menu is jumping around with the dropdown when you are going on a new page..

Comment: You said "when you hover over the a tag the white color it ..." what does it means? which a tag?

Comment: In the dropdown menu, when you hover over an element(the a tag) its grey and not white..

Comment: remove 'color: #4f87b7;' from .top-bar.top-bar .menu.menu>li:not(.search__toggler):hover>a and you are done.

Comment: @StefanLarsen ok don't remove color but add this in  your css .is-submenu-item.is-submenu-item.is-submenu-item.is-submenu-item.is-submenu-item.is-submenu-item:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}

Comment: Does not change anything :(

Comment: Well, i got it.. Should just do this " .is-submenu-item .is-dropdown-submenu-item {
  a {color:white;}
}"

Comment: Create a new question as its totally different so other user will also try to help you. They won't get by comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exact solution is to reduce or remove the css transition effect from the img tag.

Use

```
.gallery-image img {
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: none;
}
```

instead

```
.gallery-image img {
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: none;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have applied transition effect in css

```
.gallery-image img {
width: 100%!important;
max-width: none;
transition: .4s ;
}
```

change it to following

```
.gallery-image img {
width: 100%!important;
max-width: none;
transition: transform .4s;
}
```

It will solve the problem

Comment: This removes the animated transition

Comment: This is because you have applied transition on `.gallery-image img` change it to `.gallery-image img:hover` .It will work the right way

Comment: But this is the reason its happening.

Comment: Sorry, you have to apply transform property on `:hover`